# Retirar namespace ou nomes completos

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio, resharper

A minha dúvida é se existe algum atalho, comando ou função do Visual Studio que retire os namespace ou nomes completos de classes, por exemplo: para vc adicionar uma Data Annotation sem fazer um using vc tem que colocar o namespace completo System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required(), mas depois que vc fizer um using no namespace System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations vc só precisa colocar Required().

Entao o que eu quero é, em uma classe que foi utilizado namespace junto com as classes e nao foi feito using, após eu fazer os usings eu quero retirar o namespace do código, para ficar mais limpo.

Só que se eu for fazer isso na mao terei muito trabalho e queria saber se o VS faz isso de forma rapida e automatica.

Comment: Lhe respondi no GUJ Respostas: http://www.guj.com.br/40502-retirar-namespace-ou-nomes-completos#answer-50525

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A funcionalidade de refactoring do VisualStudio é muito limitada, mas com o ReSharper dá para fazer assim:

> Refactor -> Remove unused references

ou entao, simplesmente `Cleanup code` (Ctrl+E, Ctrl+C)